# Given a string S consisting only of '(' and ')', find out the length of the longest valid substring

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, stack, queue

I know there's already question on stackoverflow for this but my code is different. So i used stack to solve this question but somehow my output is not coming out right, but when i try to solve this on paper using the input testcase which gives wrong output I'm able to get the right answer, what am i missing in the code or where is it wrong?

testcase for wrong output - ))))))()()))(())))())((()()()())(((()))())

my output - 6 , expected output - 20

my code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //code
    int tc,count,max;
    cin>>tc;
    while(tc--){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        max = 0;
        count = 0;
        stack<char> store;
        int len = s.size();
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            if(s[i] == '(') store.push(s[i]);
            else{
                if(!store.empty() && store.top() == '('){
                    count+= 2;
                    store.pop();
                }else if(count>max){
                    max = count;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<max<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Literally the reason why *debuggers* exist. Single-stepping this code with your given input data, examining variable values and weighing them against your expectations would likely be incredibly illuminating. Regardless, I also see no need for a stack. All it ever holds is `'('` characters, and you could do that just as easily with a simple counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of code:

```
if(!store.empty() && store.top() == '(') {
     count+= 2;
     store.pop();
} else if(count>max) {
     max = count;
     count = 0;
}
```

consider what happens when the longest valid substring is at the end of the string: you never hit the false branch, and so you never update `max`. A minimal change to the code could be:

```
if(!store.empty() && store.top() == '(') {
     count+= 2;
     store.pop();
     if(count>max) {
         max = count;
     }
} else {
     count = 0;
}
```

where you are updating `max` every time `count` changes.

There are many more simplifications that could be made to the code, e.g. since the `stack` only contains identical values, you could replace it with an `int`.